only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks,
i want to run virtual device in android studio, but it says error: only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed
setting.graddle code is:
`def management = pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}
settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}`your text``your text`
management

plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false

}

include ":app"`

can anyone help me? please
